# SpeechRecognizer and MediaRecorder not working with same time

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have used below code of SpeechRecoginzer, I want to get confidences score of voice.

```
    private fun initSpeech() {
        mSpeech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity)
        mIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
//        mIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000000);
        mIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        mSpeech!!.setRecognitionListener(this)
    }


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onResults(bundle: Bundle) {
        val words = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)
        val scores = bundle.getFloatArray(android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.CONFIDENCE_SCORES)
        Log.e("scores", "" + scores!![0])
        Log.v("myapp", words!![0])
        tvScore.text = (scores[0]*100).toInt().toString()
}
```

When we are using above code with Media Recorder that time SpeechRecognizer class is getting error code 5.

Any one have solution please help me. That would be very helpful to me.

Thanks!

Comment: lib todo opus encode plus googl-speech-recognize at same time ...   https://github.com/rowntreerob/Google-speech-Opus-Recorder